# How to make VSCode recognize custom characters when using shortcut keys such as [Ctrl＋→]?

Tags: visual-studio-code

if we have two files

```
//a.txt
anything!
```

```
//b.txt
anythingI
```

so when a.txt opened in vscode, we can see:

```
[cursor]anything!
```

after using [Ctrl＋→], we can see:

```
anything[cursor]!
```

when b.txt opened in vscode, we can see:

```
[cursor]anythingI
```

after using [Ctrl＋→], we can see:

```
anythingI[cursor]
```

How to make b.txt look like a.txt after using [Ctrl＋→]?

### **This question is translated by machine and is subject to errors.**

**Previously, I typed [Ctrl+→] incorrectly as [Alt+→].**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put this into your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "ctrl+right",
  "command": "cursorWordPartRight"
}
```

The capital letter in `anythingI` will be seen as a *part* of a different word and so the cursor will stop just before it.  But that `I` will not be treated as a word separator when you trigger the `cursorWordEndRight`.  It is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry I made a big mistake: actually, I want to say [Ctrl+→].

Comment: I figured you did - just change the keybinding to whatever you want.  Be aware that `Ctrl+right` is probably already bound to some other functionality that you may or may not care about.